# Migrate code from a tree layout chart in version 3 to version 5

Tags: d3.js

I managed to get this code to work with some things I needed. It works on version 3 of `d3.js`.

I would like to migrate it to version 5.

I could do it in parts, such as

```
d3.layout.tree() => d3.tree()
```

but I don't know how to solve the rest of the problems, I look in the documentation and I don't understand how to make the changes.

This is my live code:

https://jsfiddle.net/z4fah7gm/

This is my code:

```
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var root = {
    "name": "flare",
 "children": [{
                "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                    "size": 3938
            }, {
                "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                    "size": 6714    }]
}


var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    rectW = 60,
    rectH = 30;

var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
});

var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000)
    .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1,3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
zm.translate([350, 20]);

root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);

d3.select("#body").style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", rectW / 2)
        .attr("y", rectH / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    });

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
    //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
    //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

    nodeExit.select("text");

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x", rectW / 2)
        .attr("y", rectH / 2)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

//Redraw for zoom
function redraw() {
  //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
      + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Comment: usually you can solve it by look up the errors in console one by one, for example there is no `d3.svg.diagonal` anymore, etc. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @soundquiet Exactly, that's what I'm doing (in fact in the question I mention that I could make this adjustment). what you mention I corrected it, but then I get an error with `tree.nodes (root)` and here I don't know how to correct it

Answer (score 1):

It is tedious to convert v3 to v4/5. Since you are stuck with the `tree.nodes (root)` problems, I tried to adjust the code to get it passed.

First, get the hierarchy structure from the `root` data.

```
var root = {
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [{
        "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
        "size": 3938
        }, {
        "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
        "size": 6714    }]
}

let rootInTree = d3.hierarchy(root, function(d){return d.children;})
rootInTree.x0 = 0;
rootInTree.y0 = height / 2;
```

Then in the `update` function, try to access nodes and links by using

```
function update(source) {
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var treeData = tree(rootInTree);
    
    var nodes = treeData.descendants(),// tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);// tree.links(nodes);

    // ... other things 
}
```

...then will pass the `tree.nodes(root)` problem, and face the next one, probably with `zoom`.

See [more examples](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) about `tree` after v3.

Comment: you are a crack, I forgot to mention that before that I also have problems with `d3.svg.diagonal ()` I have searched and `d3.linkVertical ()` maybe it can help, but I get an error, `d3.linkHorizontal (... ) .projection is not a function` :(  I really appreciate your help

Comment: @yavg I didn't work too much with tree layout, I've tried my best (demo)[https://jsfiddle.net/aw521us3/40/ ], I find an (example)[https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b024fcce8b4b9264011a1c3e7c7d70dc ], you may have a look

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I mainly like that example because I can zoom, pan, collapse the elements etc.